# Store and access data offline from a website

Tags: web, storage, offline

What is the best/easiest way to store data offline? I have a website that I only run local (it's just for personal use) so I am not using any php or sql. I have a lot of posts containing a date, a time, a description the consist of a lot of text and a few of them contain an audio file (there are very few audio files so they may be stored separately from the rest). Now I want to make a website which can show these posts at request, but since I am not using either a server or a database I'm not sure how to store them. Use of any kind of framework or library is allowed, as long as I can use it without an internet connection.

Thanks.

EDIT: JSON is a good way to read data without a server-side language, but I don't know if it's possible to or how to write to a file without a server-side language. To summarize: I want a database (for both storing and accessing) without the need for a server.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way without setting up a web or database server is to use JSON files imo. The syntax is very easy to learn!

Edit: I'd there is a better way to do this without dB setup / server side languages I'd like to hear it

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. JSON is definitely a good idea. Would you also happen to know how to write (JSON) data to a separate file (so I can save the data)? I also edited my question